# Reordering (ascending) two dictionaries with respect to values after the last _ in a string

Tags: python, dictionary

l have two dictionaries which called `dict_names` and `dict_values` composed of about 20,000 keys.
Here is two elements of the dictionary :

```
dict_names={'Dunk_g09_c03' : [Dunk_g09_c03_0159,Dunk_g09_c03_005,Dunk_g09_c03_0149,...,Dunk_g09_c03_0001],
'Bulk_g08_c07' : [Bulk_g08_c07_0256,Bulk_g08_c07_0800,...,Bulk_g08_c07_0015]}

dict_values={'Dunk_g09_c03' : [[0.45, 078,...,016],[0.48,0.12,...,0.89],...,[0.12, 0.59,...,0.23]],
'Bulk_g08_c07' : [[0.0.1,0.17,...,0.89],[0.23,0.47,...,0.45],...,[0.12,0.15,...,0.12]]}
```

l want to reorder the dictionaries in ascending order following the values after the last `_` in dict_names values . For instance :

`'Dunk_g09_c03' : [Dunk_g09_c03_0159,Dunk_g09_c03_005,Dunk_g09_c03_0149,...,Dunk_g09_c03_0001]`

becomes :

'Dunk_g09_c03' : [Dunk_g09_c03_**0001**,Dunk_g09_c03_**0002**,Dunk_g09_c03_**0003**,...,Dunk_g09_c03_**LAST**]

and

**dict_values** is reordered respecting the new order in **dict_names**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to, for each key (assuming the `d.keys()` are identical ), pair the elements by position, sort those pairs, then replace the original values with their sorted counterparts.

```
def key_func(pair):
    return int(pair[0].split('_')[-1])

for k, names in dict_names.items():
    sorted_pairs = sorted(zip(names, dict_values[k]), key=key_func)
    dict_names[k], dict_values[k] = zip(*sorted_pairs)
```